# ssh clone not working with github

Tags: git, github

I am new to Git and GitHub.

I created a new repository and tried to clone on my local machine.

It worked for https and git-readonly URLs. That is, the following worked fine:

- `git clone https://github.com/npsabari/testrepo.git`
- `git clone git://github.com/npsabari/testrepo.git`

But when I tried `git clone git@github.com:npsabari/testrepo.git`, it didn't work. It gave the following error message:

```
Cloning into 'testRepo'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

And then I tried `ssh git@github.com`, but I got the error:

```
"Permission denied (publickey)."
```

instead of the welcome message.

What should I do to fix this? What is the reason for the error?

Comment: Have you generated, updated and confirmed a SSH key?

Comment: No! and I dont know how to generate or update or confirm SSH key. Today only I started using git.. So, how to do the above all?

Comment: See my answer below, it contains a link (the 3rd) to the tutorial

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As per GitHub [help](https://help.github.com/), the [error you're getting](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey) is related to wrong SSH configuration. Please follow indications for [setting up SSH for GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) and check accordingly.

Comment: This solved! I have another doubt, if I use other machines to clone my repository, do I need to generate SSH key in that machine and add that to my github account? or else I can only SSH from one machine..?

Comment: It is better to generate a key for each machine.

You can copy one from one machine to another but it is not recommended since as soon as one machine is compromised all machines using the same key will be.

A middle solution would be to have a key on a USB stick and use flags to tell that you want to use them. However, better is to stick with one key per machine :D

Comment: Sabari and @MihaiMaruseac In fact I tried to copy key from one EC2 instance to another and get it failed. Only new generated key works I guess?

Comment: No, copying keys also works. That's what I always do when I switch personal computers and it always works.

Comment: while this does say what the problem is, it doesn't say how to solve it; this seems like a "princess is in another castle" answer to me https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Answer (score 8):

You can either follow the below document to add your key to `ssh-agent` 
https://help.github.com/en/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

or you can run the following command to execute it temporarily

`ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/github_rsa; git clone git://github.com/npsabari/testrepo.git'`

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the problem was that the machine I was using was being authenticated by a repository rather than by my user, despite having a ssh key registered to my GitHub account.

You can check who is authenticated with

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

This happened because I had a ssh key configured as Deploy Key to one of the repositories I was working on.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the error is that you don't have your public key (~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) uploaded to GitHub. Add it to your account(you may do this through the web panel provided by github) and it will work.

Comment: How to do that? And I dont hv the file id_rsa.pub in ~/.ssh folder. How to generate it?

Comment: Is uploading the public key somethinng that the owner of the repository must do, or does it have to be done by the person doing the cloning?

Comment: would you know if it necessary for public repositories?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this - only once ever - that the key generated by `ssh-keygen` was broken. Checking the private and public key-files, they have the correct syntax, length, et.c.

It. Just. Didn't. Work.

On the same machine, I re-generated a key-pair. This finally let me connect to github via ssh.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add that if you need to use `sudo`, it could interfere as the SSH key is not bound to that user. You might want to edit the rights before using `git` rather then after.

Comment: underrated answer. had to change directory ownership and clone without sudo and it worked. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually first you should do generate ssh keys and then save them in your account.

See the following link for more details

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to clone.
`1. SSH`
`2. HTTPS`
In my case first one had given similar issue as you got, but then I tried using `HTTPS` way by running following commands.
`git clone https://xyz`
Before that run this command `git remote -v`. This should show
`1. git-url(fetch)`
`2. git-url(push)`
If you see these both upon running command, it tells you that you got `push` right as well `fetch` rights. After you have configured, and set proxy properly, if you still find problem, this solution I have explained should work. If your `SSH public key and private key` are wrong then, you must fix that first before anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution for linux:

1. Run: find -al ~/.ssh
2. Copy the text inside of your "id_rsa.pub"

(if you do not have a ssh file then create one)

3. Go to your GitHub account and click on your profile picture in the top right corner. Select "Settings" from the drop-down menu.
4. In the left sidebar, click on "SSH and GPG keys."
5. Click on the "New SSH key" button.
6. Paste your public SSH key into the "Key" field.
7. Try to clone with SSH again

Answer (score 1):

## In 2023, it was a nightmare to me.

No reference can help me find a solution. After some late night research I found something that worked for me. So I shared if anyone needs and can save some time.

1. In your terminal run the following command:

   ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"
2. You can skip adding any name, just press enter.
3. You can add passphrase or can skip (not recommended though)
4. Now you need to copy the code from the newly generated .pub key, to do that run the following code.

   cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
5. Login to Github.com, go to the setting page and then navigate to `SSH and GPG keys`
6. Click on `New SSH key`
7. Give any name and paste the code from .pub file and Save it.

Now you should git clone :)