# EC2: Clone private git repository on ubuntu root directory

Tags: git, amazon-ec2

I am trying to clone my GitHub private repository on Ubuntu EC2 instance root directory. I have generated SSH key on my EC2 instance following this stack-overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51584381/8107458). I can clone the repository using generated SSH key on to my home directory using following command:

```
sudo git clone git@github.com:myusername/testwebapp.git
```

But with the same command when I tried to clone it on root directory which is in my case `/srv/`, it gives me following error message:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I though it would be related to user and user group permissions, I tried to change permissions it didn't work. Don't know what I am missing?

Comment: You've forgotten to mention that you used `sudo` for the second clone. It's important.

Comment: Can you show us the exact command you used? Are you trying to clone as root or as your user account?

Comment: @phd, Yes, you are right. I edited my question.

Comment: @Brian61354270 Yes, I edited it in my answer. I am trying to clone as my current user account i.e. `ubuntu` user.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Does the clone work with or without `sudo`?

Comment: @AnonCoward yes, I need to be a root user and generate ssh key on root user dir. I can clone git repo now.

Comment: @erik258 Hi, So when I am ubuntu user I cannot clone because I have not generated and added ssh key to root user `.ssh` directory. As per the @Anon Coward my issue resolves.

Comment: try to avoid `sudo` and know why you need it when you use it; you'll learn a lot