# Is it required to regenerate SSH key for new EC2 instance when cloning a github repo via SSH URL?

Tags: github, ssh, amazon-ec2

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11585695/248616) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31921521/248616), it seems that connecting to github repo via SSH protocol requires a newly generated key.

I just tried today on my EC2 instance and failed to *git pull* my github repo; i.e. reusing a key pair generated on another EC2 instance is not working.

So I want to raise the issue here so that we all can confirm this - Is it required to regenerate ssh key for new EC2 instance when git clone a github repo?

p.s.

What I have done and failed on *Ubuntu Server 14.04* are as below.

## ssh key files

- cloned key in `~/.ssh`

[image]

- public key registered in github

[image]

## calling git

- run `ssh -vT git@github.com`

[image]

- run `git clone git@github.com:MY_USER/MY_PROJECT.git MY_FOLDER` get *Public key denied* error

Comment: still I don't see the information how does the failed pull look like. What about `GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -vvv git pull`?

Comment: That command get me the `error public key`

Comment: And with `GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -vvv`?

Comment: It say -vvv not found @@

Comment: ok ... this way: `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv"` (missing quotes).

Comment: A bit busy overhere. Sorry. I'll try and back to you soon.

Comment: My ssh connection crashed so I restart it and now things work. Thank you so much @Jakuje to get us here. Picked yours answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I want to raise the issue here so that we all can confirm this - Is it required to regenerate ssh key for new EC2 instance when git clone a github repo?

## in brief

No need for re-generated key.

## details

Reusing the key from different instance SHOULD WORK too, but you need to place it to the proper location with the correct permissions.

You may try

- Restart your SSH connection to the EC2.
- Specify the private key via GIT_SSH_COMMAND prefix

  `sudo GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY" git clone git@github.com:USER/PROJECT.git YOUR_LOCAL_DIR`

p.s.

You can clone over `HTTPS` without any SSH key.

Comment: Please clarify `proper location` and `correct permissions` - I copy the keys to ~/.ssh (both private and public files) and permission for private to be 400

Comment: Also when running `ssh -vT git@github.com` I got the success authentication